# Cannot assign instance of javax.swing.event.EventListenerList to field javax.swing.AncestorNotifier.firstInvisibleAncestor

Tags: java, swing, exception

I am a little bit lost here. I have a Java program that runs on most computers without any trouble. But on some of them the following Exception is thrown:

Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of javax.swing.event.EventListenerList to field javax.swing.AncestorNotifier.firstInvisibleAncestor of type java.awt.Component in instance of javax.swing.AncestorNotifier

The Java version seems to be up to date on this machines. Has anyone any clue what might cause this exception?

Comment: Can you show the code indicated by the exception message as well as any related code and other important background information? It should be obvious, the line of code especially, that it is critical to our understanding of your problem.

Comment: I will do it as soon as possible. Unfortunately I cannot recreate the error on my machines, some of the users of my program send me screenshots of this exception. I already requested .log files. Just wanted to see if maybe this is something obvious. Google seems not to know about this at all. :(

Comment: Just for the record - it was an Serialization error. It is less platform independent than I thought.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to us on this. I hope you were able to fix this with this knowledge.

Comment: Fixed it by switching to http://xstream.codehaus.org/ - abandoning the java serialization.